# Short novel where a backwards nation invades the U.S. to lose, but wins

Tags: story-identification, novel

Thirty years ago, in the 1990s, when my father was a kid he read a book that he has never found since - he describes it as a very short novel, maybe about a centimeter thick / 80 pages long.

It's set in the modern day (seven decades ago). A very low-technology nation, somewhere around the Stone Age, decides it needs to fix this. And the best way to resolve this is, of course, to lose a war with the U.S.. So they declare war on the U.S., clearly unprovoked, and invade.

Sadly for them, they win. The U.S. doesn't want to fight back (or something similar?), and they march right up to Washington D.C. with longbows and take it over. They are freaked out - "This wasn't supposed to happen! That's not how it works!"

My father said that today, librarians would take it off the shelves once they saw the 1950s cover, irrespective of the contents.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It's not clear here that there are any actual science fiction aspects to this story; can you clarify that?

Comment: "The Mouse That Roared" is a fun story but it isn't science fiction.

Comment: @JohnRennie Sadly, although I agree with you, and SFE notes "minimal SF elements" in the series as a whole (with the obvious exception of *Mouse on the Moon*), *Roared* is listed by both SFE and ISFDb.

Comment: What's wrong with the 1950s cover?? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/6/63/The_Mouse_That_Roared_first_edition.jpg?20120624032039 Or do you mean this one https://www.abebooks.com/servlet/BookDetailsPL?bi=31202907686&searchurl=fe%3Don%26sortby%3D17%26tn%3Dmouse%2Broared&cm_sp=snippet-_-srp1-_-image1#&gid=1&pid=1 (which seems to be a 1982 cover; goofy and arguably mildly sexist, but ???)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not have any sci-fi or fantasy elements.

Comment: @Möoz It's SF because (a) in our Earth there is no Duchy of Grand Fenwick between France and Switzerland, and (b) the Q bomb.

Comment: @user14111 As it stands, the question itself has no SFF elements. That the (currently) highest voted answer pins it as SFF is not counted.

Comment: @BenBolker I don't think the book would have been marked 35¢ in 1982.

Comment: I was misled by the "A1982" reference number.

Comment: @user14111 The fact that the Duchy of Grand Fenwick doesn't exist isn't a sci fi element, it's just an ordinary fictional element.  Places / people that don't exist are a staple of most fiction.  As for the Q-bomb, **||SPOILER ALERT||** that isn't a sci fi element either, since it turns out not to work.

Comment: @MishaR There is no consensus [definition of science fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definitions_of_science_fiction) or fantasy, and AFAIK this site has not adopted any official definition. Users vote to close questions as off topic based on their own idiosyncratic definitions. I'll take the opinions of SF professionals over those of a bunch of internet randos. P. Schuyler Miller in ASF, July '55, p. 151: "It presumably qualifies as borderline science-fiction ..." Anthony Boucher in F&SF, June '55, p. 75: "It isn't going too far to call this s.f. ..."

Comment: @MishaR That the bomb fails to detonate is beside the point. The hypothetical isotope quadium and its properties are purely science-fictional. It beats me that a question about an alternate history yarn (the U.S. was actually never conquered by invaders wielding longbows) with a bomb using a fictional isotope is considered off topic, while a question about an image of a guy with funny looking ears is considered on topic.

Comment: @user14111 Again, the bomb turns out to be nothing, so it doesn't really matter that some in-universe characters think it might work. As for whose word you take for whether or not it's science fiction, I certainly don't demand that you take mine. For what it's worth, I elected to leave the question open. But like you said - this site runs on votes. If you prefer an authoritative decree with a famous name behind it, cool, but it isn't the deciding factor on here.

Comment: @user14111 - If the SF professionals decide to participate here they can have a say in what is on-topic and what is SF&F. Until then of course it's up to the "bunch of internet randos" as you put it.

Comment: For what it's worth I have no opinion one way or the other on whether or not the Q-bomb is enough to count it as science fiction. I mentioned it as the single element I'm aware of that might qualify, that's all.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is *The Mouse That Roared*, a  novel by Leonard Wibberley. Also a movie starring Peter Sellers in multiple roles.

From [Wikipedia's plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mouse_That_Roared#Plot):

> The tiny (three miles by five miles) European Duchy of Grand Fenwick, supposedly located in the Alps between Switzerland and France, proudly retains a pre-industrial economy, dependent almost entirely on making Pinot Grand Fenwick wine. However, a California winery makes a knockoff version, "Pinot Grand Enwick", putting the country on the verge of bankruptcy.

> The prime minister decides that their only course of action is to declare war on the United States. Expecting a quick and total defeat (since their standing army is tiny and equipped with bows and arrows), the country confidently expects to rebuild itself through the largesse that the United States bestows on all its vanquished enemies (as it did for Germany through the Marshall Plan at the end of World War II).

There's a minor SF element in the form of an experimental doomsday device, the "Q-bomb".

Comment: Thank you! This fits everything and is presumably it. I'll check it out; on initial investigation it seems to be hilarious.

Comment: I thought the Q bomb was a bluff?

Comment: And [the sequel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mouse_on_the_Moon_(novel)) has them landing on the moon ahead of the USA and Russia with a rocket powered by exploding wine.

Comment: @DavidW: Not a bluff, but ultimately a dud.